# How can I dynamically remove HTML form elements generated by Zend Form API, using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zend-form

I am using PHP Zend Form API library, which generates HTML form code for multiple elements and provides a mechanism to add field elements dynamically via JavaScript.

The Add works great, but how can I remove an element?

Also, if you look at the code, when new elements are added, the index count is updated.  Thus, if I do remove an element, and later add one, my index number will be incorrect.  I think it will be a bit of a pain to actually *renumber* the indices.  Thus, I think it's best to remove the code that adds the index and just not put one in.  I believe that way they will be numbered properly anyway on form submit

Still though, how can I remove individual element rows?  The ones that are wrapped by `<fieldset>` tags?  I am looking for a good direction on how to do it.

```js
function add_row() {
  var currentCount = $('form > fieldset > fieldset').length;
  var template = $('form > fieldset > span').data('template');
  template = template.replace(/__index__/g, currentCount);

  $('form > fieldset').append(template);

  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="return add_row()">Add a new form row</button>

<form action="" id="selection" method="post" name="selection">
  <fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <label><span>Flow:</span><input name="points[0][flow]" type="number" value="3"></label><label><span>Pressure:</span><input name="points[0][pressure]" type="number" value="3"></label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <label><span>Flow:</span><input name="points[1][flow]" type="number" value="3"></label><label><span>Pressure:</span><input name="points[1][pressure]" type="number" value="3"></label>
    </fieldset><span data-template="&lt;fieldset&gt;&lt;label&gt;&lt;span&gt;Flow:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;input type=&quot;number&quot; name=&quot;points&amp;#x5B;__index__&amp;#x5D;&amp;#x5B;flow&amp;#x5D;&quot; value=&quot;&quot;&gt;&lt;/label&gt;&lt;label&gt;&lt;span&gt;Pressure:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;input type=&quot;number&quot; name=&quot;points&amp;#x5B;__index__&amp;#x5D;&amp;#x5B;pressure&amp;#x5D;&quot; value=&quot;&quot;&gt;&lt;/label&gt;&lt;/fieldset&gt;"></span>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I rewrote `add_row()` method to have a strictly increasing index, instead of using fieldset count, since removing a row removes index at that row, and does not keep track of last index.  Adding rows must add index that is larger than the last index.

After deleting/adding rows indices may be sparse, i.e. `0, 2, 6, 16`.  They transparently get populated into the object I have on PHP side, with ordered indices starting from 0.

`add_row()` is now this:

```
<div id="newRowIndex" style="display:none">1</div>

<script>
function add_row()
{
    var newRowIndex = $('#newRowIndex').text();
    $('#newRowIndex').text(++newRowIndex);
    var template = $('form > fieldset > span').data('template');
    template = template.replace(/__index__/g, newRowIndex);

    $('form > fieldset').append(template);

    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: does the index number matter with your back-end functionality ? if not just remove the part which is giving indexes to your fields

Comment: index number does not matter for my application as long as I end up with a contiguously numbered array on the back end.  I think just removing the index will work. Due to the library generating the first form row I may end up with `points[0]` for the first row and then repeated `points[]` for the added rows

Comment: @hassan, PHP may be related to the question, since there may be solutions involving adding PHP code as per Zend\Form.  For example, I'm currently looking into a way to add a button to the form as per Funk Doc's answer, which involves me adding and editing PHP code, in conformance with Zend\Form API. True that there may be purely HTML + JS solutions but it does not have to be limited to those.

Comment: you didn't mentioned any thing related to your php code used their;

Comment: turns out the indexing matters.  If I remove the index, it breaks down the structure of POST array, i.e. places `flow` and `pressure` into separate subarrays, instead of keeping them in one

Comment: you said that 'index number does not matter for my application .... ' and due to this i've suggested to remove the php tag;

Comment: however, you may remove the indexes from pressure too, or re-sort your `$_POST['pressure']` and `$_POST['flow']` arrays .

Comment: Unrelated to PHP, I meant that as long as POST array sets looks like `array('flow' => 1, 'pressure' => 2)`, it does not matter what index number that set ends up at.  But removing index from HTML form yields arrays like `array('flow' => 1), array('pressure' => 2)`, which separates individual row values into separate subarrays.  In short, I need to keep the index strictly increasing when I add elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a button to each row

```
<fieldset>
     <label><span>Flow:</span><input name="points[0][flow]" type="number"    value="3"></label>
     <label><span>Pressure:</span><input name="points[0][pressure]" type="number" value="3"></label>
     <button class="removeLine">Delete Row</button>
</fieldset>
```

and a little jquery

```
$(function(){
    $("#selection").on("click",".removeLine",function(){
        $(this).closest("fieldset").remove();
        return false;
    });
});
```

You can add the remove button dynamically.
just put addRemove() before the return false in the add_row function and include the below

```
function addRemove(){
  $("form fieldset fieldset").last().append("<button class='removeLine'>Delete Row</button>");
}
```

Comment: that is pretty cool.  I'll have to figure out how to update the add row template in `<span data-template...` though, as it's generated for me dynamically :)

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote `add_row()` method to have a strictly increasing index, instead of using fieldset count, since removing a row removes index at that row, and does not keep track of last index.  Adding rows must add index that is larger than the last index.

After deleting/adding rows indices may be sparse, i.e. `0, 2, 6, 16`.  They transparently get populated into the object I have on PHP side, with ordered indices starting from 0.

`add_row()` is now this:

```
<div id="newRowIndex" style="display:none">1</div>

<script>
function add_row()
{
    var newRowIndex = $('#newRowIndex').text();
    $('#newRowIndex').text(++newRowIndex);
    var template = $('form > fieldset > span').data('template');
    template = template.replace(/__index__/g, newRowIndex);

    $('form > fieldset').append(template);

    return false;
}
</script>
```